# PDO SELECT Что я делаю не так

Tags: php, select, pdo

```
public function select($select,$table, $where)
{
    $data = $this -> pdo->prepare('SELECT :select FROM :table WHERE :where ');
    $data -> bindParam(':table',$table);
    $data -> bindParam(':select',$select);
    $data -> bindParam(':where',$where);
    $data ->execute();

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: вы не так оформляете свой вопрос с описанием возникших проблем..... но вообще нельзя подставлять подготовленные переменные вместо `table` и в выборке между `select` и `from`.....

Comment: Мне нужно выбрать даные юзера с login = $login i я никак не могу понять как работать с подготовленными переменными.
делал так 
$sql="SELECT `login` FROM `tbl_user` WHERE id=? ";
           $name = $this -> pdo -> prepare($sql);
            $name->excute(array($user));

Comment: подготовленные переменные подставлять можно только в значения...например у SELECT в условие WHERE - куда как раз пользователь может прислать свои данные.....в INSERT запросе подставлять в VALUES ........ а вот динамически их подставлять вместо всего остального нельзя....да и бессмысленно .......... попробуйте почитать http://phpfaq.ru/pdo

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю что нужно написать так:

```
public function selectById($id)
{
    $data = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT `login` FROM `tbl_user` WHERE `id` = :id');
    $data->bindParam(':id',$id, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $data->execute();

    return $data->fetchAll();
}
```

В подготовленных запросах нельзя указывать динамически select и table. Только параметры для поиска. При однотипных запросах это дает прирост производительности, если бы вы хранили `$data` в переменной и не создавали бы её каждый раз.

и вот ссылка по теме http://phpfaq.ru/pdo

Comment: Спасибо! Буду разбираться !